# Linux Mint mouse wheel not working

Tags: linux, mouse, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint 17 Qiana
and wanted to scroll down using mouse wheel
with no luck yet.
so far I have tried  "Gpoint Device settings" and 
marked use middle button emulation , use wheel emulation
and selected button 2' but it doesn't seems to change the mouse behaviour.

Comment: just want to use the wheel mouse to vertically scroll down and up in web browser terminal etc...

Comment: All of mine have worked out of the box since the early 2000s. This doesn't appear to be about programming.